# Start appium inspector, when appium server started programmatically

Tags: automation, appium, appium-android

I have started appium server programmatically (using appium service builder)

now I need appium inspector to inspect elements.
Is there any way to start inspector programmatically or I need to remove my code and use the appium desktop application for server session and inspect elements.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If the device is attached to the same host as that of appium server, use uiautomatorviewer under Android SDK to inspect the elements in Android.
For iOS, it is recommended to use Appium Desktop version itself.

Answer (score 0):

Appium inspector is separated from appium server build. You will get separate installation file for appium inspector. You can start it independent of the appium server. Try with the latest version.